# How to magically add the file field to each entry in a bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

In the context of biblatex its possible to `bibstyle=reading`, this will produce bibliography including `abstract` and `annotation` fields.

As well as `file` field linking to the `file.pdf`, the reference. If the bib entry has `file` set like:

```
@book{some-book,
 author     = {The Author},
 title      = {The Book Title},
 abstract   = {Bla bla bla},
 annotation = {Bla bla bla},
 file       = {some-book.pdf}
}
```

I have `file.bib` containing many entries, like:

```
@book{some-book,
 author     = {The Author},
 title      = {The Book Title},
 abstract   = {Bla bla bla},
 annotation = {Bla bla bla}
}
```

Following idea above I should go to each entry and add:

```
 file       = {some-book.pdf}
```

That will be a lot of work. Is it possible to automate it some way?

How to add `file` field to each entry without having to go to each entry and manually add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easily possible to add arbitrary field contents to entries with Biber's sourcemap features.

With

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=false]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match={.*}, final]
      \step[fieldset=file, fieldvalue={$1.pdf}]
    }
  }
}

% just to print the 'file' field
\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{file: \path{#1}}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\printfield{file}\finentry}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,worman,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Entries with file field.]

You would add to each entry the equivalent of

```
file = {<entrykey>.pdf},
```

to all entries that don't already have a `file` field.

---

You don't even need RegExes here, you could just say

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, final]
      \step[fieldset=file, origfieldval, final]
      \step[fieldset=file, fieldvalue={.pdf}, append]
    }
  }
}
```

which would overwrite an existing `file` field. The `overwrite=true` is needed because an `append` step must formally be able to overwrite a field. You can guard against overwriting a pre-existing `file` field by adding

```
      \step[notfield=file, final]
```

as first step.

---

But it seems rather pointless to add a field `file` with the sole contents `<entrykey>.pdf` to all entries. The information you are adding is a very simple function of information that is already present in the `entrykey` field, after all.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\DeclareFieldFormat{fakefile}{file: \path{#1.pdf}}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\printfield[fakefile]{entrykey}\finentry}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,worman,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Would produce the same result but without the need to map any field contents.

Comment: Concerning last part of the answer, is the file path provided this manner a link so that I can click and go to that file?

Comment: @KcFnMi Not in this code, no. `\path` normally does not link stuff, but instead of `\path{XYZ}` you could say something like `\href{file:XYZ}{\path{XYZ}}` and things should be linked (provided you load `hyperref`). This is independent of the solution you use and would be the same if you just gave `file` in the `.bib` file.

Comment: And should I worry about `\Url Error ->\url used in a moving argument`?

Comment: @KcFnMi You should always worry about errors. I get no error from the MWEs though, so I suggest you ask a new question with a short example document that reproduces the error.

Comment: Besides ctan.math.illinois.edu/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf, do you recommend other references about `DeclareSourcemap`?

Comment: @KcFnMi The `biblatex` manual (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) has an example section than the Biber documentation, but apart from that there is not a lot of other 'systematic documentation' out there. You can find plenty of examples on this site and elsewhere, though.

Comment: Why in the RegExes code you use `overwrite=false` but after that, for the non RegExes code you use `overwrite=tru`?

Comment: @KcFnMi In the RegEx the `overwrite=false` avoids overwriting an existing `file` field. (The second `\step` is not allowed to overwrite an existing `file` field.) The non-RegEx-solution needs `overwrite=true` to work properly, because the third `\step` with `append` formally needs to be able to overwrite the `file` field. In consequence that means that this solution overwrites an existing `file` field.

Comment: What about the usage of `final`?

Comment: @KcFnMi `final` means that the following steps will only be executed if this step was 'done successfully'. The steps following `\step[fieldsource=entrykey, final]` for example will only be executed if the entry has a non-empty `entrykey` field. In this case most finals are not needed (because every entry must have a non-empty `entrykey` field and `.*` will match all contents), but there are cases where `final` is  important, so I got into the habit of adding `final` in most of my `\step`s.

Comment: @KcFnMi That information is not accessible as far as I know. You'd have to fake this with `\perdatasource{<filename.bib>}` and copy-and-paste.

Comment: Sorry, deleted comment/question and asked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489288/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-bib-file-to-set-as-the-vale-of-a-bib-field. But the way you said I have to type file name two times, \perdatasource{<filename.bib>} and \addbibresource{<filename.bib>}.