# Can I use variables as entry key in bib files?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I would like to write something like

```
@string { subtype = "the-subtype" }

@string { entry = "the-entry1" } 
@book{entry,
entrysubtype  = subtype,
file          = subtype # "/" # entry # ".pdf",
title         = {Title}type" } 

@string { entry = "the-entry2" } 
@book{entry,
entrysubtype  = subtype,
file          = subtype # "/" # entry # ".pdf",
title         = {Title}
```

In my experience it looks like I can use variables to set value of tags but it don't work for entry key.

Can I use variables as entry key in bib files?

Answer (score 1):

That won't work. The entry key is special and not a normal `<field> = {<value>},` pair as all other fields, where `@string`s work. In particular the entry key has a slightly different 'value' syntax than the fields, which makes it impossible to tell whether one wants the text as written or a `@string` replacement. Normally BibTeX knows that you want the `@string` because there are no braces around a `@string`

```
title  = {Lorem ipsum}, % normal value
author = sigfridsson,   % @string
```

We can't do the same with the entry key because it is always given as

```
@<type>{key,
  ...
}
```

without braces.

I also doubt that it is a good idea to have several `@string`s with the same identifier (`@string {entry = ...}`).

---

As in your previous question [How to magically add the file field to each entry in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488948/35864) I would suggest a source map to produce the `file` field on the fly from information in the `entrykey` and `entrysubtype` fields. I don't quite know what you are after in your real-world application, but certainly for the example that seems to be much, much cleaner than repeating the same `file = subtype # "/" # entry # ".pdf",` sequence in each entry and overwriting the relevant `@string`s each time.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrysubtype, final]
      \step[fieldset=file, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=file, fieldvalue={/}, append]
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, final]
      \step[fieldset=file, origfieldval, append]
      \step[fieldset=file, fieldvalue={.pdf}, append]
    }
  }
}

% just to print the 'file' field
\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{file: \path{#1}}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\printfield{file}\finentry}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@string{subtype = "the-subtype" }

@book{the-entry1,
  entrysubtype  = subtype,
  title         = {Title},
} 

@book{the-entry2,
  entrysubtype  = subtype,
  title         = {Title}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{the-entry1,the-entry2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Title (n.d.). file: the-subtype/the-entry1.pdf.//Title (n.d.). file: the-subtype/the-entry2.pdf.]

Alternatively, you can still build the contents of the field directly within `biblatex` without the sourcemap, though that becomes more fiddly when you want to combine several field values into one string.