# How do I get the name of the bib file to set as the vale of a bib field?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, luatex, biber

Slightly changing topic from [How to magically add the file field to each entry in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488948/how-to-magically-add-the-file-field-to-each-entry-in-a-bib-file/488977?noredirect=1#comment1235322_488977).

I have the following:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey]
      \step[fieldset=file, fieldvalue={ref/}]
      \step[fieldsource=entrysubtype]
      \step[fieldset=file, origfieldval, append]
      \step[fieldset=file, fieldvalue={/}, append]
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey]
      \step[fieldset=file, origfieldval, append]
      \step[fieldset=file, fieldvalue={.pdf}, append]
    }
  }
}
```

And in the bib:

```
@string { subtype = "thesubtype" }
```

Name of bib file is `thesubtype.bib`.

Instead of (manually) setting the value of `subtype` inside the bib I would like to set it programmatically on the `DeclareSourcemap`. Which might be a good approach to that?

I guess one approach might be to through in some python. And I heard lualatex brings lua language, curious if that can be used here.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the `.bib` file is not accessible for use in source maps or other operations. But the name is known at least at a very early stage when Biber processes `\perdatasource` (I presume it is forgotten later on). If you think 
access to the file name would be a useful feature for the general public, please specify what *exactly* you want (Do you want the file name of an entry to basically act as a normal `.bib` field? Do you want to be able to refer to the file name just in a source map?) and open a feature request at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues.

---

In the meantime, here is a work-around that uses `\perdatasource` and encompasses `\addbibresource` to keep redundancy at a minimum. The solution exploits that `\perdatasource` allows us to get a glimpse of the `.bib` file name. Since you need one such `\perdatasource` map for every `.bib` file in the document, so it seems natural to combine the source map with `\addbibresource` directly.

Note that `\addentrysubtyperesource` takes the `.bib` file name *without* the file extension (unlike `\addbibresource` which needs the extension).

Note further that there are several source maps in the example and their order matters. The `\addentrysubtyperesource` calls should come before any other source map constructs.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\newcommand*{\addentrysubtyperesource}[1]{%
  \addbibresource{#1.bib}
  \DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
      \map{
        \perdatasource{#1.bib}
        \step[fieldset=entrysubtype, fieldvalue={#1}]
      }
    }
  }
}

\addentrysubtyperesource{\jobname-one}
\addentrysubtyperesource{\jobname-two}


\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey]
      \step[fieldset=file, fieldvalue={ref/}]
      \step[fieldsource=entrysubtype]
      \step[fieldset=file, origfieldval, append]
      \step[fieldset=file, fieldvalue={/}, append]
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey]
      \step[fieldset=file, origfieldval, append]
      \step[fieldset=file, fieldvalue={.pdf}, append]
    }
  }
}


% just to print the 'file' field
\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{file: \path{#1}}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\printfield{file}\finentry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-one.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-two.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author  = {Emma Sigfridsson},
  title   = {Chemistry},
  date    = {1998},
  journal = {Journal of Chemisty},
  volume  = {48},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {135-164},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby, Humphrey (1980). On the Importance of the Civil Service. file: ref/kcfnmifilenames-one/appleby.pdf.//Sigfridsson, Emma (1998). ‘Chemistry’. In: Journal of Chemisty 48.2, pp. 135–164. file: ref/kcfnmifilenames-two/sigfridsson.pdf.]